# delete user from zk attendance device using c# api

Tags: c#, asp.net, zkteco

I have set of ZK attendance device that using static IP address. I'm enrolling users to this machines using zkmkeeper.dll in C#. now i want to delete old users from these machines using system. I can't find the function to delete users, but there is function to disable. I want to delete that users permanently from devices.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when deleting userInfo or enrolled data but i found a workaround

```
objCZKEM.DeleteEnrollData(machineId, userId, machineId, 12)
```

according to the documentation :
 12 indicates deleting the user (including the fingerprints, card number and password).

Comment: is it necessary to use machineId twice.

Comment: According to the [Manual](https://github.com/hmojicag/NetFrameworkZKTecoAttLogsDemo/blob/master/ZKTeco_Standalone_SDK_Development_Manual_V2.1_A.2-EN.pdf) yes 
check page 77

Answer (score 0):

@Yuuuucef, thank you for reference. According to documentation

```
5.2.4.3 DeleteEnrollData
    VARIANT_BOOL DeleteEnrollData(LONG dwMachineNumber, LONG dwEnrollNumber,
LONG dwEMachineNumber, LONG dwBackupNumber)
```

The values of dwMachineNumber and dwEMachineNumber must be the same

Answer (score 0):

After trying many ways I have finally found a way. clear all user data using `axCZKEM1.ClearData(Convert.ToInt32(number), flag)` and re enroll the data using Database.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found works for me.
Use the SSR_deleteEnrollData function with only 3 parameters (while notice asks for 4 parameters)

> SSR_deleteEnrolData(dwMachineNumber , dwEnrollNumber , dwBackupNumber)

Maybe depends of device version.